# Get-SPUesr : You must specify a valid user object or user identity

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint

I was trying to copy CSV file in to SharePoint 2010 list by using PowerShell. However, when I try to import user names into a people picker field I am getting the error:

> Get-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity

Here is the powershell I used:

```
$Item["Assigned To"] = Get-SPUser -Identity $i."AssignedTo"  -web "http://.../"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What does $i."AssignedTo" look like?

The `Identity` parameter expects a valid logon name (DOMAIN\username).

---

EDIT: Given that the AssignedTo field contains the users first and last name, you could query the /_catalogs/users list to get the ID for the user in the site (assuming that the first and last name matches the FullName field in the list) and then use that id to lookup the user.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$web = get-spweb http://.../
$query = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = [string]::Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", $i."AssignedTo")
$list = $web.GetList("/sites/dev/_catalogs/users")
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$i = $items[0]
$id = $i.Id

$user = $web.AllUsers.GetById($id)

$Item["Assigned To"] = $user
```

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response,                                                       The "AssignedTo" column in the CSV file is First Name + Last Name like John Doe

Comment: I've updated my answer according to this information.

Comment: By the way, the easiest solution would be to save the username in the CSV file and use this (and your original script)